# Do not scroll with anchor, simply change div?

Tags: html

Lemme explain my situation here: I'm trying to make a layout for a website. This goes in a small box, and can include HTML and CSS, yet not javascript. I have a small box inside this, with tabs to link to different things. This is done via putting the divs in a box and using anchor tags to get to them.
This is totally fine, until the page has a scrollbar. Then, when you click on the anchor tag, it scrolls. This is a problem as if moves the whole page, and even the tabs aren't visible anymore. Is it possible to get this to work, without any javascript, or should I just put this in an iframe hosted on my own website and get past it that way? :/
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple scrolling div will do the trick. No javascript needed. Much better than an iFrame, I think.

http://www.htmlite.com/faq015.php

Comment: This is in a div, yet I don't want it to scroll. What it does is has all of the divs inside a 'structure' div, and then moves them. The user doesn't scroll, they click on a link, for example #about, and then the div repositions. So basically, I don't think that'll work, but I can try. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like are looking for "scroll" functionality without the actual scroll bars. Maybe, in that case, you DO need an iFrame and then use CSS to hide the scrollbars.